# Is there a way to pass a nested function as an argument to the parent function in Python?

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing, nested-function

I'm coding in Python and I basically want to define different versions of a function while having it all encapsulated in one function. I know I can achieve this by just passing a string argument to the parent function and using if stmts like in `open("myfile.txt", "r")`. I could also define `func_version1()` outside of `func()` and call it like `func(func_version1)`, but is there a cleaner way to do this? I'm imagining something like the code below:

```
def add(a, b, func=adult):

    def adult(a, b):
        return a + b

    def kid(a, b):
        return int(str(a) + str(b))

    return func(a, b)
```

Using this definition, calling something like `add(1, 2, adult)` or `add(1, 2)` would return 3, and `add(1, 2, kid)` would return 12. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you would use a dictionary for this

```
def add(a, b, func='adult'):

    def adult(a, b):
        return a + b

    def kid(a, b):
        return int(str(a) + str(b))
    fn_map = {'adult':adult,'kid':kid}
    return fn_map[func](a, b)


add(1, 2, 'adult')
add(1, 2, 'kid')
add(1, 2, 'bob') # ERROR
```